# django-rest-framework-social-oauth2: error 400 - redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth

I've been trying to add google login to my django app following this tutorial:
https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

By following exactly the instructions, everything works fine in local.

However, when I try to replicate the same on the server, I get the following error on the redirect page of the login:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8000/auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```

What is strange to me is, in my google developer console, I have set up the correct redirect url in my app, as follows:

```
https://mydjangoapp.com/auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```

And I have also put 'mydjangoapp.com' under 'Authorised JavaScript origins'.
So my question is, why google keeps telling me that the redirect url is

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```

which is not the one I have set up in the console? Perhaps there is something obvious that I'm missing here. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

> Why google keeps telling me that the redirect url is

Because your application is sending its in your code the app is running on http://localhost:8000 and if you are using a client library its probably adding the rest automatically.

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```

The redirect uri must exactly match what you are sending from your application.

You need to add

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```

Javascript origin is only needed if your code is using javascript.

This video will show you how to fix the error. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

If you want your code to send https://mydjangoapp.com then your going to have to be running it from https://mydjangoapp.com probably and you may need to figure out how to configure it so that it is running from the correct host.